# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/vue.js?v=31b05063' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, pinia

I don't know how to solve this problem.
When I started project vue3.js , console show me this error.
This import in pinia store.
I tryied change first line with import to
"import Vue from 'vue';"  (without curcy braces), but error don't disappear.

```
import { Vue } from 'vue';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import moment from 'moment';
import _ from 'lodash';

import router from '@/router';
```

[image]

Comment: you should `import { createApp } from "vue"`. See how you [create an app in Vue 3](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#the-root-component)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using latest version of vue , vue3
this code
import { Vue } from 'vue';
is no longer global instance